# Can I get the html.HiddenFor / Html.Hidden create an id or should I just create it manually?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I do this:

```
<%=Html.HiddenFor(o => o[i].HobbyId) %>
```

and it creates a hidden input but without `id` (just `name`, I need `id`).

Can I make it create an `id` also ?

***atm I do it like this:***

```
<%=Html.HiddenFor(o => o[i].HobbyId, new Dictionary<string, object>{{"id", " _ "+i+"__HobbyId"}}) %>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A cleaner way to do it is

```
<%=Html.HiddenFor(o => o[i].HobbyId, new {id = " _ "+i+"__HobbyId"}) %>
```

but aside from that your existing method is ok. If you really want a simple syntax you can create an extension method that calls HiddenFor, but that hardly seems worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do something such as:

```
@Html.Hidden(
    string.Format("{0}ObjectId", Model.BindingPrefix), 
    Model.ObjectId
)
```

Which produces this:

```
<input id="customerModel_ObjectId" name="customerModel.ObjectId" type="hidden" value="3a44d3eb-58ec-4229-9fe0-e420d9855bb7">
```

The id and name convention is consistent and produces stable id and name values that do not change.  This works perfectly for me.

So to convert your example to my format:

```
@Html.Hidden(
    string.Format(" _ {0}__{1}", i, HobbyId), 
    HobbyId,
)
```

...that should get you what you want as well.  Hopefully, I didn't inject any syntax errors while typing this out.  :)

Comment: ...of course this is using Razor syntax from MVC3 RC2, but you get the idea and can easily translate this to aspx syntax.