# JavaScript in MVC Editor template doesn't render properly

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm moving some controls from a view to an Editor. In my Editor I have this HiddenFor:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmailDataVariables)
```

I have some javascript that tries to read it (this works in my original page, but not in the view):

```
var myValue = document.getElementById('EmailDataVariables').value;
```

The `HiddenFor` renders out like this (which breaks the above JavaScript):

```
<input id="EmailTemplate_EmailDataVariables" 
    name="EmailTemplate.EmailDataVariables" 
    type="hidden" 
    value="myData">
```

Should I just assume the control will always be named `EmailTemplate.EmailDataVariables` and write my javascript like this:

```
var myValue = document.getElementById('EmailTemplate.EmailDataVariables').value;
```

Or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

1) Assume the ID will always be `EmailTemplate_EmailDataVariables` and update your JS accordingly.

2) Give it a unique ID that you will always know.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmailDataVariables, new {id = "EmailDataVariables"})
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604009/can-i-get-the-html-hiddenfor-html-hidden-create-an-id-or-should-i-just-create)